# Binary decision, evaluating Bayesian probit regression?

Tags: r, posterior, probit

Laplacian logistic regression. I have a training set of data and an evaluation set. The response is binary. I have to verify the models by calculating posterior predictive on the evaluation set. Last step compare the two models' predictive distribution variance.

First I trained the model using MCMCprobit() function from R.
How do I verify the correctness on the evaluation set? How do I calculate posteriors for each observation from the evaluation set?